# bin/dev no detecta cambios Tailwind en Rails 7 en contenedor Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind

Estoy ejecutando bin/dev.  Las clases de Tailwind que uso en mi HTML funcionan.  Pero si hago algún cambio en las clases, no se refrescan automáticaente en el navegador; tengo que detener el servidor y volver a ejecutar bin/dev

A alguien le pasa lo mismo?  Saben cómo solucionarlo?

Gracias.

**Procfile.dev**
web: bin/rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0

css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch

Rails 7.0.4.2

Ruby 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solución la encontré en la documentación de la gema tailwindcss-rails.

> If you are running rails tailwindcss:watch on a system that doesn't
> fully support file system events, pass a poll argument to the task to
> instruct tailwindcss to instead use polling: rails
> tailwindcss:watch[poll]. If you use bin/dev then you should modify
> your Procfile.dev.

Le pasé el argumento [poll] a tailwindcss:watch en el archivo Procfile.dev.  Quedó así:

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch[poll]
```

Ahora, al usar bin/dev para iniciar el servidor, si hago algún cambio en las clases de mi HTML, solo con refrescar la página se reflejan los cambios.  Ya no tengo que detener y volver a iniciar el servidor.